# How to inline a variable in function definition

Tags: evaluation, compile

I need to compile a function `g` that calls an external function `f`. `f` and `g` are defined as such:

```
r = {0,0,1};
f = # - r &;
g = Compile[{{a, _Real}}, f[a], CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

But this way `r` will be held, and `g` will assume it to be a real number instead of a vector, throwing type error when trying to find `a - r`. How can I inline `r` such that `f = # - {0,0,1}&`? `Evaluate` doesn't work because the result will be `f = {#, #, #-1}&`.

Comment: What about `Replace[f, OwnValues[r], All]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you re-write it like this it should work:

```
r = {0, 0, 1};
f = a - r;
g = Compile[{{a, _Real}}, f, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

Testing it like below:

```
g[2]
```

I get the following result without errors:

```
{2., 2., 1.}
```